# permutation containing substring

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

So, i just want to check if my answer to this question is correct or not.

Question : Determine the number of non-repeating strings with length 9 consisting only of numbers (0-9) or vowels (a, i, u, e, o, A, I, U, E, O) that contain the substrings "B16" and "uA".

To answer this question, we treat "B16" and "uA" as a single element, so that there will be 6 elements to arrange. 2 position is already filled by "B16" and "uA" and the remaining 4 position can be filled by 15 x 14 x 13 x 12. And then the arrangements of 6 elements is 6!. So the final answer is 15 x 14 x 13 x 12 x 6!. Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

If none of the characters can repeat (i.e they can appear only once in your substrings of $9$ characters), you are correct till the point that there are $2$ positions already filled by (B$16$) and (uA).

But if you are calculating remaining $4$ position to be filled as $15 \times 14 \times 13 \times 12$, you are permuting them as well. So to again arrange them as part of $6!$ will bring in duplicates.

You should rather select $4$ characters out of remaining $15$ as $15 \choose 4$ and then multiply by $6!$.

So your answer should be ${15 \choose 4} \times 6!$